# Suppose that $\Gamma$ is a curve $y = f(x) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, where $f$ is continous. Show that $m(\Gamma) = 0.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $\Gamma$ is a curve $y = f(x) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, where $f$ is continous. Show that $m(\Gamma) = 0.$

Attempt: Suppose that that $\Gamma$ is a curve $y = f(x) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, where $f$ is continous. Then since $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, we have for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $|x- a|$ and $x,a \in \mathbb{R}$. imply $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$.

I dont know what to do .... I need to show that the function is measureable. Could someone please help? Thanks

Comment: In $\Gamma$ the graph ?

Comment: And it would be really "great" to know what in the world does $\;m(\Gamma)\;$ mean *for you* ....

Comment: I am assuming $\Gamma$ is the graph. So I have to find the measure of the curve, $m(\Gamma)$.

Comment: Do I have to show $f$ is measurable if for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$, the set $f^{-1}([-\infty, a)) = {\{x \in E: f(x) < a}\}$? where $E \subset of R^2$?

Comment: I am stuck ...and my book just mentions measurable functions briefly

Comment: What about the space filling curve ?

Comment: I assume $m$ is lebesgue and your curve has finite length? You can cover your curve with $\lceil \frac{L}{\epsilon} \rceil +1$ squares (where $L$ is the lenght of your curve) which have measure $\epsilon^2$. Monotonicity and subadditivity of the measure covers the rest.

Comment: i dont know about that

Comment: @ReneSchipperus a space filling curve of the form $y = f(x)$ would be quite remarkable.

Comment: @UmbertoP. i meant just the normal space filling $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: My previous comment can be extended to curves of infinite length by considering the curve as a countable union of finite length curves.

Comment: If you look at the right side of this page, you can find http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1158540/show-that-m-gamma-0-where-gamma-is-a-curve-y-fx?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with an interval $[a,b]$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$ there exists an index $n$ with the property that if $[a,b]$ is partitioned into $n$ equal pieces, the graph over each piece is contained in a rectangle of height $\epsilon$ and width $\frac{b-a}{n}$.  Consequently the graph of $f$ over the whole interval $[a,b]$ is contained in a union of rectangles whose total area does not exceed $\epsilon(b-a)$. Now let $\epsilon \to 0^+$ to get that the graph of $f$ over $[a,b]$ has measure zero.

The whole graph can be written as a countable union of such graphs restricted to bounded sets.

Answer (score 1):

By Fubini's theorem, if $I_\Gamma(x,y)$ is the indicator function of $\Gamma$, $$m(\Gamma) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \int_{-\infty}^\infty dy\; I_\Gamma(x,y)$$
But for each $x$, $I_\Gamma(x,y) = 0$ for all but one $y$, so $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy \; I_\Gamma(x,y) = 0$.